# Docker ругается на Bitmap.SaveAdd

Tags: c#, docker

Приложение работает в контейнере докера, в который добавлена библиотека `System.Drawing` через

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
    libc6-dev \
    libgdiplus \
    libx11-dev \
    fontconfig \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

И, когда дело доходит до подобного кода

```
Bitmap someBitmap = ...    
someBitmap.SaveAdd(anotherBitmap, encoderParamsN);
```

Я получаю ошибку `System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented.` на моменте с `SaveAdd`

Как можно засунуть в докер ~обновлённую~ библиотеку `System.Drawing` или сделать что-то иное, что бы метод `SaveAdd` заработал?

Comment: Хм, судя по [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.saveadd?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_SaveAdd_System_Drawing_Image_System_Drawing_Imaging_EncoderParameters_), этот метод не реализован в .Net Core 1.*, 2.*. Вероятно, вы используете одну из этих версий? Значит надо перейти на другую, желательно самую новую: .NET 5.0

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проект сейчас на .Net Core 3.1, в билдере докера записи `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env` и `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime`. Попробую поэкспириментировать с .NET 5.0

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov с .NET 5.0 так же получаю ошибку

Comment: Похоже всё плохо: [тыц](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1886). А судя по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033514/5045688), дело в деньгах. PS: какой энкодер хотите использовать?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov с каждым днём ненавижу докер всё сильнее -_- Придётся изобретать новый способ создавать гифки, без использования `System.Drawing`